# SELECT * FROM TABLE(pipelined function): can I be sure of the order of the rows in the result?

Tags: oracle, plsql, pipelined-function

In the following example, will I always get “1, 2”, or is it possible to get “2, 1” and can you tell me where in the documentation you see that guarantee if it exists?

If the answer is yes, it means that without `ORDER BY` nor `ORDER SIBLINGS` there is a way to be sure of the result set order in a SELECT statement.

```
CREATE TYPE temp_row IS OBJECT(x number);
/

CREATE TYPE temp_table IS TABLE OF temp_row;
/

CREATE FUNCTION temp_func
RETURN temp_table PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
    PIPE ROW(temp_row(1));
    PIPE ROW(temp_row(2));
END;
/

SELECT * FROM table(temp_func());
```

Thank you.

Comment: :Yes ,if you reverse the order of PIPE ROW ,then it will give you output 2,1 otherwise 1,2 .And if you want that for specific order ,then add an order by clause in your select query.Otherwise the select query will return the data based on the PIPE ROW sequence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that there's anywhere in the documentation that *guarantees* the order that data will be returned in.

There's an old [Tom Kyte thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4447489221109#9850260021416) from 2003 (so *might* be out of date) which states that relying on the implicit order would not be advisable, for the same reasons as you would not rely on the order in ordinary SQL.

> 1st: is the order of rows returned from the table function within a
>   SQL statement the exact same order in which the entries were "piped"
>   into the internal collection (so that no order by clause is needed)?
>
> ...
>
> Followup   May 18, 2003 - 10am UTC:
>
> 1) maybe, maybe not,  I would not count on it.  You should not count
>   on the order of rows in a  result set without having an order by.  If
>   you join or do something more complex then simply  "select * from
>   table( f(x) )", the rows could well come back in some other order.
>
> empirically -- they appear to come back as they are piped. I do not
>   believe it is documented that this is so.
>
> In fact, collections of type NESTED TABLE are documented to explicitly
>   *not have the ability to  preserve order*.

To be safe, you should do as you always would in a query, state an explicit ORDER BY, if you want the query results ordered.

Having said that I've taken your function and run 10 million iterations, to check whether the implicit order was ever broken; it wasn't.

```
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 10000000 loop
  3      for j in ( SELECT a.*, rownum as rnum FROM table(temp_func()) a ) loop
  4
  5         if j.x <> j.rnum then
  6            raise_application_error(-20000,'It broke');
  7         end if;
  8      end loop;
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer, that 2003 answer from Tom Kyte is really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This procedural logic works differently to table-based queries. The reason that you cannot rely on orders in a select from a table is that you cannot rely on the order in which the RDBMS will identify rows as part of the required set. This is partly because of execution plans changing, and partly because there are very few situations in which the physical order of rows in a table is predictable.

However here you are selecting from a function that does guarantee the order in which the rows are emitted from the function. In the absence of joins, aggregations, or just about anything else (ie. for a straight "select ... from table(function)") I would be pretty certain that the row order is deterministic.

That advice does not apply where there is a table involved unless there is an explicit order-by, so if you load your pl/sql collection from a query that does not use an order-by then of course the order of rows in the collection is not deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

The AskTom link in accepted answer is broken at this time but I found [newer yet very similar question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9539868000346452669). After some "misunderstanding ping-pong", Connor McDonald finally admits the ordering is stable under certain conditions involving parallelism and ref cursors and related only to current releases. Citation:

> Parallelism is the (potential) risk here.
> As it *currently* stands, a pipelined function can be run in parallel only if it takes a ref cursor as input. There is of course no guarantee that this will not change in future.
> So you could run on the *assumption* that in *current* releases you will get the rows back in order, but you could never 100% rely on it being the case now and forever more.

So no guarantee is given for future releases.

The function in question would pass this criterion hence it should provide stable ordering. However, I wouldn't personally trust it. My case (when I found this question) was even simpler: selecting from collection specified literally - `select column_value from table(my_collection(5,3,7,2))` and I preferred explicit pairing between data and index anyway. It's not so hard and not much more longer.

Oracle should learn from Postgres where this situation is solved by `unnest(array) with ordinality` which is clearly understandable, trustworthy and well-documented feature.