# Get index of element in VARRAY collections

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This may seem straightforward, but I couldn't find the answer in docs.

As with nested tables, we can use `TABLE()` with `COLUMN_VALUE` pseudocolumn for varrays.

```
create or replace type NUMBER_ARRAY as VARRAY(10) of NUMBER;

create table TAB_WITH_ARRAY(
  ID    NUMBER,
  VALS  NUMBER_ARRAY)    

insert into TAB_WITH_ARRAY
select 1, NUMBER_ARRAY(1,2)
from dual
union all
select 2, NUMBER_ARRAY(1,2,3,4,5)
from dual

select t.id, c.column_value
from TAB_WITH_ARRAY   t,
     table(t.vals)   c
```

However, unlike nested tables, `VARRAY` is an ordered collection type, and I want to preserve that order. Is there a way to get not only value but also index of each element in SQL?

---

Yes, in my tests the order of output was right and I could just use `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION BY` primary key of my main table to generate indexes, but experience taught me not rely on ordering unless it was manually specified.

So is there a built-in way to access indexes of elements in array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the index of VARRAY items after converting to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559647/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-varray-items-after-converting-to-a-table)

Comment: Thanks, @SudiptaMondal, that's quite close. However, I'd love to see 1) an entirely SQL solution, 2) a solution that works with a column of arrays, not a single array.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16713002/458741

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       c.COLUMN_VALUE,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.ROWID ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS idx
FROM   TAB_WITH_ARRAY t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE( t.vals ) c
```

Or, from Oracle 12c, use `OUTER APPLY` and `ROWNUM`:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       v.*
FROM   tab_with_array t
       OUTER APPLY (
         SELECT v.COLUMN_VALUE,
                ROWNUM AS idx
         FROM   TABLE( t.vals ) v
       ) v
```

Which, for your sample data, both outputs:

> ```
> ID | COLUMN_VALUE | IDX
> -: | -----------: | --:
>  1 |            1 |   1
>  1 |            2 |   2
>  2 |            1 |   1
>  2 |            2 |   2
>  2 |            3 |   3
>  2 |            4 |   4
>  2 |            5 |   5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b25e756014c9c39cd8470c3b0a52cf91)*

Comment: This `ORDER BY rownum` thing is cool. I suppose I could isolate this part of a query and use it to preserve the order of output.

The issue is I never found a firm statement in docs that `TABLE()` outputs rows in the same order the elements are stored in the array.

Other than that, nice answer! Thanks!